# In IDA how can I define a data address as a struct and array of datatype

Tags: ida, struct

As the title says im a bit lost on how to get something in the data section to be recognized as a struct or an array of structs or an array of strings etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Struct: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Array: Numeric keypad <kbd>*</kbd>

Comment: Nice to know these shotcuts thanks.
However it still seems to say int when it should be an array of my struct.

`seg002:00AEAD78 ; int stru_AEAD78[]
seg002:00AEAD78 stru_AEAD78     sStorageItem <0>        ; DATA XREF: Recv16_Character:loc_408EF2w`

Or is it possible to have two definitions at the same place?

Comment: Ah never mind, I had to set the type of it with Y